# Get the return of another macro in huff

Tags: huff

Let's say I have two macros:

```js
#define macro TOTAL_SUPPLY() = takes (0) returns (0) {
    [TOTAL_SUPPLY_LOCATION] sload   // [supply]
    0x00 mstore                     // []
    0x20 0x00 return                // []
}

#define macro DOUBLE_TOTAL_SUPPLY() = takes (0) returns (0) {
    // Get return of TOTAL_SUPPLY.  // [TOTAL_SUPPLY]
    0x2                             // [0x2, TOTAL_SUPPLY]
    mul                             // [0x2 * TOTAL_SUPPLY]

    0x00 mstore
    0x20 0x00 return
}
```

How would I get my `DOUBLE_TOTAL_SUPPLY` macro to get the return value of `TOTAL_SUPPLY`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In it's current form, you can't. Remember, calling a macro is the same as copy pasting the code into where you're currently executing, including the return which ends the transaction!

What you can do to get around this, would be to make a wrapper macro, one that returns, and one that doesn't.

`TOTAL_SUPPLY_RETURNS` returns, and calls `TOTAL_SUPPLY` which does not. So you can use `TOTAL_SUPPLY` in future code.

(remember, if you use `TOTAL_SUPPLY` a *lot* you might want to consider making it a function instead of a macro)

```js
#define macro TOTAL_SUPPLY_RETURNS() = takes (0) returns (0) {
    TOTAL_SUPPLY()                  // [supply]
    0x00 mstore                     // []
    0x20 0x00 return                // []
}

#define macro TOTAL_SUPPLY() = takes (0) returns (1) {
    [TOTAL_SUPPLY_LOCATION] sload   // [supply]
}

#define macro DOUBLE_TOTAL_SUPPLY() = takes (0) returns (0) {
    TOTAL_SUPPLY()                  // [TOTAL_SUPPLY]
    0x2                             // [0x2, TOTAL_SUPPLY]
    mul                             // [0x2 * TOTAL_SUPPLY]

    0x00 mstore
    0x20 0x00 return
}
```